# Fastest possible toaster

Tags: physics, hard-science, technological-development, energy, food

The year is 2016, your budget is in the tens of billions, and your job is to create the fastest possible toaster: specifically, the transition from regular, cold slice of bread to hot, lightly browned, crisp toast must be as short as possible. Practicality is irrelevant. The toaster cannot burn the bread; it has to be a proper slice of toast.

How fast can one get, and what would such a machine look like? What sort of theoretical limits cap the speed of a toaster?

As a bonus question, how fast could a toaster produced if the only limitations are the laws of physics (and the definitions of bread and toast), thus allowing theoretical technology, planet-sized structures, etc

EDIT: To clarify, the question is not about highest rate of production, but about making the actual toasting process fastest.

Comment: TrEs-2b, why did you change the budget requirements?

Comment: If people want to edit my question, how about some better tags? I couldn't find any more relevant ones than the ones I specified...

Comment: I was just thinking, toasting my bagel the other day. Too bad there's no "microwave toaster"
With a big budget, I suspect one could come up with a rapid heating solution, then use a laser to finish to the desired surface toasty-ness. I think I'd use a scanning laser, and toast raster lines on the bread, possibly with a sensor to measure the change in reflectance.

Comment: the problem with lasers as I see it is that it seems like there is a sort of gradient of toastyness throughout the toast, whereas with a laser I imagine it would just brown the surface and leave everything else cool.
I am imagining one could get down to pretty small fractions of a second with laminar bursts of superheated air.

Comment: @HDE226868 I felt that the 'tens of billions of dollars' was over explaining it, that simply saying it was unlimited provided the same information, I apologize.

Comment: TBH I was a bit thrown off. I don't know SE well enough to say if that was appropriate or not, but I now that I think of it I actually think I prefer the edit. If someone can describe a continent-sized machine that can bake a toast within nanoseconds, I want to hear about it.

Comment: @dn3s Okay, sorry. You can rollback my edit, if you want.

Comment: Strap a pair of STS SRBs onto its sides and light them off.  Your toaster ought to reach 6 km/s.

Comment: I think that current toasting technology is pretty close to as fast as possible.  You might be able to reduce the time by 25 or 50% at most, but the main limiting factor is conduction of heat through the bread, which you can't make any faster without changing the laws of physics (or changing your bread).

Comment: I think the bigger question is why toast is so important to this society. Can they not survive the two minute wait for a piece of delicious, crispy bread?

Comment: How about we take that money and develop a toaster that can toast bread consistently, evenly, and reliably every time you use it?  Or is that still speculative-fiction physics, even in 2016?

Comment: Close-voters: Please don't vote to close without leaving commentary. OP: I believe the issue being identified here is that the question has no apparent value towards worldbuilding; it is primarily a question about physics and mechanics.

Comment: @sh1 We actually had that back in the 70s; It accurately detected how well-toasted the bread was with a simple sensor that detected colour change in the bread and used that to accurately measure how well it was toasted. Alas, it didn't sell very well, as people assumed that the lack of a knob meant that they couldn't adjust it for different breads - without realising that with this toaster, they didn't need to do that. So it tanked commercially, and we were left with the inferior toaster technology we live with now.

Comment: @user867 Some people want warm bread and some people want charcoal, that knob is critical or it's no good as a toaster.

Comment: @user16295 Just add a neural interface to determine the person's preferences. Then make a four-slice version of the same product for the larger families.

Comment: It's an interesting question, but I can't see what it has to do with Worldbuilding - it's a hypothetical question about nothing much. Perhaps if you could explain how it relates to building a world it could be reopened :)

Comment: @IStanley: I'm not the OP, but I could certainly imagine this being asked in the context of The Jetsons or something. The idea being to figure out some crazy way to do something we 2016ians don't think about much, in a way that makes us wonder why we've been doing it so wrong for like a hundred years. Alternately, something like the Fallout universe, where they often show crazy experimental tech failing in parody of our current obsession with doing stuff faster, stronger, better.

Comment: @MichaelS, it's not a question of whether people might try and do it (that's a given), it's about how the answer would help build a world. "How fast can I make toast" doesn't really have a "why?" That puts it in a world building context. How would answering this question help with the details of a world?

Comment: @IStanley: If you are trying to show a Jetsons-style world, you need to first think about what plausible methods we might use to make better <whatever>. From flying cars to laser-based toasters to robotic dogs, each little detail needs at least a little research. I'm not saying it's necessarily what the OP intended, but I can imagine it having that use. An intermediate world might be one set in, say, 2025, with half the first-world utilizing a variant of that crazy laser-toaster invented back in 2016 by some eccentric billionaire.

Comment: @MichaelS, if that's what the OP is doing, then sure, we can help with that (but from the phrasing of the question I'm not confident it is). But this, as it stands, is a pure hypothetical question with no context. Regardless, the question needs to be edited to better fit a world building context before it can be reopened - a reopen can be requested before that but given that 4 separate people voted to close it for the same reason, it's unlikely to happen without a change.

Comment: i think it should define whats a proper slice of toast, how thick the slices are and how dry we want the toast inside... a melba toast is different from a grilled slice of bread... Or am I too picky?

Comment: can my world not value fast toasting simply as a given? If you want a specific cause, perhaps a runaway AI type scenario would be suitable, or a toast-themed cult.

Comment: I can't think of a more suitable SE site for this. It was closed on Physics (I realize now that I didn't do the proper migration process... sorry). If someone wants to migrate this to a more appropriate location I would be fine with that. I just thought the speculative nature of the question fit the format. I may not be writing a book, but this is part of the worldbuilding process that is my imagination.

Answer (score 7):

The point of toasting bread as we all know is the creation of 6-acetyl-1,2,3,4-tetrahydropyridine and to get it crispy enough to hold up in a BLT.

Unfortunately, that molecule of the gods can only be formed in the 285°F/ 140°C and 320°F/ 160°C range. Hotter than that you get bitter flavors and charcoal. This reduces the efficacy of lasers and supernovas.

Your best and mundane bet is to pass it under the salamander and call it a day.

Comment: Pass it under the salamander? What does that mean?

Comment: @Samuel it is a commercial infrared broiler. http://www.ifoodequipment.com/webcura/files/255084_ax-slm.jpg

Answer (score 5):

Simple.

Create a machine that finishes new slice of toast every 1 second (or 0.001 seconds). This is extra simple as multiple slices can be baked in parallel.  Then, at any point, you can wait only 1 second (or 0.001 seconds) to pick a freshly made toast. Rest is thrown out as garbage.

This approach can reach any speed you want. It will just require much more parallel system and produce huge amount of uneaten toasts.

Comment: +1 This is the solution that most people ignore, but is exactly correct for this question.

Comment: "specifically, the transition... must be as short as possible. Practicality is irrelevant." This is not about making a toast available on as short notice as possible, this is about making the actual toasting take as little time as possible (I have now clarified my question to reiterate this)

Comment: @dn3s My answer is still valid. It is still best answer if you are asking for "shortest time between deciding to have a toast to having that toast".

Comment: that is the best answer for that question, but that is not my question. I am asking for "shortest time between bread and toast", considering the *individual piece of bread*. You are getting confused by the fact that it is common for humans to eat toast after deciding they want toast. Im my question, the human is irrelevant as far as toast production is concerned; The focus is on the toast itself.

Answer (score 4):

## 26s (perfectly toasted) 11s (good enough)

Regardless of how you heat it, the limiting factor is how fast the heat propagates through the bread without heating the surface to much. From King-Inks answer, the limit is 160° C, and the goal core temperature is 140° C.

I am assuming a 1cm slice of bread, heated from both sides.

Thermal data required to model heat flow.

- Thermal conductivity of bread: [$0.00072–0.00064 \space W \space cm^{-1}°C^{-1}$](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1365-2621.1982.tb11071.x/abstract)
- Heat capacity: [$2.93 \space kJ \space kg^{-1}°C^{-1}$](http://www.nzifst.org.nz/unitoperations/appendix7.htm)

Together with a typical bread density of 200 g/L, I used a method consisting of slicing the bread into a large amount of individual slices, and calculate the heat flow between them is small time increments.

If you relax the restrictions a little, say allowing a surface temperature of 180°C and only requiring half the bread to reach 140°C, the toasting can go as fast as 11s.

We can not make that so much better, because we are limited by conductive heat flow. A little internal heating, with for example microwaves, may shorten the time a little, but it is not a good idea considering quality. (As anyone who have tried can confirm.)

Comment: I like this, I think it could serve as a base for other answers. I don't think that the thermal conductivity of bread needs to be the limit; aside from conduction there's convection and ratiation. Another answer mentions lasers/microwaves, and I am imagining some sort of grid of super-thin needles spewing hot air driven through the toast at a controlled speed.

Comment: You could use little microprobes through the side to dump heat into the center directly and reduce the time needed to propogate through the slice.

Answer (score 2):

### 48 msec

#### Approach

So what you'll want is a multifrequency laser.  Since there is no such thing, then what you'll do is use a MASER (microwave amplification by the stimulated emission of radiation - a microwave laser) plus an IR or optical laser.

The purpose of the microwave is to deposit heat through the depth of the bread.

The purpose of the IR/optical laser is to brown the surface and make it toasty.

#### Powerful lasers

I know there are IR lasers at least 10x more powerful and probably MIRACL (mid-infrared advanced chemical laser) is 100x more powerful than this one.

Pretty picture of a 15 KW $CO_2$ laser.
[image: Pretty picture of a 15 KW $CO_2$ laser]

#### Energy to toast bread

[This site claims](http://energyusecalculator.com/electricity_toaster.htm) that it takes a 1200 W toaster 2 minutes (120 seconds) to toast two pieces of bread.

*I know there's a lot of wasted energy in the toaster (hot air escaping the top but I don't know how to scale it down)*

$$E = P * t = 1.2 kW \times 120 sec = 144 kJ$$

Since we're interested in a single piece of bread, divide that by 2 to get 72 kJ.

#### How long for the laser to toast bread

We need our combined lasers to deposit 72 kJ of energy into the bread (this seems way too large).

Our MIRACL laser can deliver 1,500 kW of power so:
$$ t = \frac{72 kJ}{1500 kW} = 0.048 sec $$

MIRACL can toast your bread in 48 millisecond.

Comment: 70 kJ is enough to [flash about 20 g of water into steam](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=70kJ+%2F+((water+specific+heat)+*+80+deg+C+%2B+(water+heat+of+vaporization))), so I think you might be overdoing it a little.  You have got me curious though, I think when I get home I'll try microwaving some bread to see if it makes edible toast.

Comment: I think just microwaving will make it soggy and then hard (it'll drive out the moisture).  I think you'll need both surface heating and heating in depth to get it done right.  Without doing the heat transfer equations, I have no feel for what the proportions ought to be.

Comment: and I agree.  The numbers I got were for how much power a toaster takes to toast bread.  I couldn't find anything on how much energy it takes to toast bread.

Comment: The energy is almost certainly too high, but I like your approach.

Comment: @2012rcampion I make cheese sandwiches with the microwave, and I can confirm that microwaving it will only make it warm and soggy.

Comment: @XandarTheZenon Are you sure that doesn't have more to do with the cheese than with the process of microwaving? I always assumed that it does. @ 2012rchampion, yay for science!